# How do I get the node ID from a view row?

Tags: php, drupal, view

I'm using `Drupal`. I have a module which loads a form onto a node. In my module I used

```
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {$node = arg(1);}
```

which got the `nid` each form was on.

Now I have created a view which displays full nodes but my nodes aren't getting the `nid` displayed.

I tried using something like

```
$node = node_load($rows->nid);
```

but it didn't return anything.

Basically I have a view page which displays about 10 nodes, and I'm trying to find the `nid` of each node in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the views custom field module which will give you access to the $data object for each row.  Included in that will be the nid as `$data->nid`.  You can also gain access to it in a `views-row.tpl.php`.  If you've got the devel module (which is a must, really), you can use `dsm(get_available_vars());` to pretty-print all of the variables available to that template or just `dsm($data);` to pretty-print the data object in your views custom field (`dsm()` uses Krumo which is very handy).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {$node = arg(1);}
```

This code only works if the user is on a node page. It doesn't matter if the path is aliased. 
So in Views, it won't work.

If you are building a View that display nodes, you can add node:id field to get the node ID of the node that the row belongs. No need to use Views Custom Filed (or Views PHP module if you are on Drupal 7) i  I believe.

If you are trying to get node ID of a referenced View, add a relationship to the other node via node reference field first.